# Understanding object variable assignment behaviour

Tags: java

I am in some sort of weird problem in Java. I've nailed down the whole problem while debugging it. It happens at these 2 lines:

```
q=p;
q.addPair(2,3);
```

notes: p,q is a new class I've defined. In this class, it has a `public function addPari(int, int)`.

Here is what I expected: copy `p` to `q`, then change `q` use `q.addPair()`, but leave `p` the same as before.

I thought this could work, but somehow, it turns out `q.addPair(2,3)` will change both `p` and `q`. Anyone can help me about that?

Comment: Java never copies anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q=p;
```

does not actually copy. It means modifying `q` will also modify `p` as they're the same instance.

If you want `q` to be a new object, you need to use `new`:

```
q = new MyObject(p);
```

In other words, you're using a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) to create a new copy of `p`. If your class doesn't have a copy constructor you'll need to create one: it needs to be able to create a new object from an existing one. It can do this by copying over the appropriate values from the given instance `p`.

Comment: Just a note on this; Java doesn't supply copy constructors by default so you'll have to implement it yourself in the class of which `P` and `Q` are instances.

Answer (score 0):

Java assigns by reference, so you would need to do a deep copy in order to copy one object into variable of the same type but then have two seperate objects.

Take a look at this: http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/deepcopy_and_shallowcopy.php

Answer (score 0):

With `q=p;` you don't 'copy' p to q, but you instead create a reference for q that points to the instance of p. Now the 2 variables point to the same object.